# std::min_element with std::vector<Eigen::Vector2f>

Tags: c++, eigen3

I'm trying to find the min element as follows:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

#include <Eigen/Dense>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
bool isLeftOf(const Eigen::Vector2<T>& a,
              const Eigen::Vector2<T>& b) {
  return (a.x() < b.x() || (a.x() == b.x() && a.y() < b.y()));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::vector<Eigen::Vector2<float> > points;
  points.push_back(Eigen::Vector2<float>(-1, -1));
  points.push_back(Eigen::Vector2<float>(1, -1));
  points.push_back(Eigen::Vector2<float>(0.5, 0));
  points.push_back(Eigen::Vector2<float>(1, 1));
  points.push_back(Eigen::Vector2<float>(0, 1.5));
  points.push_back(Eigen::Vector2<float>(-1, 1));
  points.push_back(Eigen::Vector2<float>(-0.7, 0));

  Eigen::Vector2<float> outpointa = min_element(*points.begin(),
                                                *points.end(), isLeftOf<float>);

return 0;
}
```

But I get compiler error:

**...\algorithm(9199): error C2675: unary '++': '_FwdIt' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
with
[
_FwdIt=Eigen::Matrix<float,2,1,0,2,1>
]**

How to overcome this?

Comment: `std::min_element` accepts a range of iterators. What's with the `*` there?

Comment: `*points.begin(), *points.end()` -> `points.begin(), points.end()` && `min_element` -> `*min_element`. `xxx.begin()` is an iterator. Dereferencing that iterator (by using `*`) gives you the elements. Standard algorithms do not want elements. They want iterators or ranges.

Comment: @milleniumbug, @Fureeish actually without `*` I get an errors:   main.cxx:103:25: errors: 
no viable conversion from 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>>>>' to 'Eigen::Vector2<float>' (aka 'Matrix<float, 2, 1>')
Matrix.h:273:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 1, 0,

Comment: Do yourself a favor:  This is a case where the keyword `auto` is your friend:  `auto outpointa = min_element(points.begin(), points.end(), isLeftOf<float>);` -- If you have a good enough C++ based editor, you will see what that `auto` actually is.

Comment: Thank you Paul. Compiler gives me the following type: `std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<Eigen::Matrix<float,2,1,0,2,1>>>>`. It is too complicated... Could it be somehow simplified?

Comment: The return value of `std::min_element` is an iterator, not the actual value.  To get the value, you need to dereference the iterator.  So simply: `auto outpointa = *min_element(points.begin(), points.end(), isLeftOf<float>);`  -- Now check what `auto` gives you.

Comment: Thank you Paul! Now I can see that the output is `Eigen::Vector2<float>`. If you (or anybody who wrote comments above) summirize this information as an answer (not a comment) I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to provide iterators to min_element

this will do , no need to dereference the iterators.

```
Eigen::Vector2<float> outpointa = min_element(points.begin(),
                                                points.end(), isLeftOf<float>);
```

Comment: If I remove `*` then I can't assign the result of the expression to `Eigen::Vector2<float> outpointa`. I get errors mentioned above in comments

Comment: use             auto outpointa = min_element(*points.begin(),
                                                *points.end(), isLeftOf<float>);